# Is it possible to install a package only in current project with PIP

Tags: django, pip

I am working both on Python/Django and nodejs.

There are 2 commands which are very similar:
  npm for node
  pip for python

npm is able to install third party package only for a selected project (in the node_modules project subfolder). npm can also install globaly the package on the system. There is an option for that.

pip seems to only install globals packages. Thats mean i can not have a "pip_module" folder in my project ?

Thanks

Comment: look at http://blog.zoomeranalytics.com/pip-install-t/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use Virtual Environments.

Install virtualenv:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Create Environment:

```
cd your_project_folder
virtualenv .myprojectvenv
```

Activate Environment:

```
source .myprojectvenv/bin/activate
```

And now all packages will be installed only for this environment.

To exit virtualenv:

```
deactivate
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what virtualenv is for. Each project should have its own virtualenv; once it is activated, pip will only install for that virtualenv.